# How to Use For Loop in Python to Create List?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a data set, and a sample looks like this:

```
ID_1    ID_2    
97353   959
9723    168
128     743512
124564  14599
16149   14149
```

I'm trying to create a list using a for loop which would combine the IDs on the same lines and produce e.g.:

```
[[97353, 959], [9723, 168]...]
```

So far, I have written:

```
list1 = []
for i in df:
    list1.append(i)
```

However, this just produces an output that looks like:

```
['9', '7', '3', '5', '3', '\t', '9', '5', '9', '\n',...
```

Could anyone suggest how to amend the for loop to produce the output I'm trying to get? Thank you!

Comment: This happens because `df` **is not** a Pandas `Dataframe`, but instead a string.

Answer (score 1):

Extract each of the columns as a list, then create the list of lists using a zip list comprehension, or by using list on a zip object. For example, you get data in the desired form from two lists like so.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

You can use either of the below expressions to get what you're looking for

```
list(zip(l1,l2))

[[x,y] for x, y in zip(l1,l2)]
```

If you are using pandas, you can extract columns as lists like so

```
ID_1_list = df['ID_1'].tolist()
ID_2_list = df['1D_2'].tolist()
```

Just replace df with the name of your dataframe.

Putting all of the above together:

```
ID_1_list = df['ID_1'].tolist()
ID_2_list = df['1D_2'].tolist()
my_data = list(zip(ID_1_list, ID_2_list))
```

Comment: The OP doesn't specify how they've made the dataframe. Should I assume pandas?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. The problem I'm having with implementing this is that the data is in .txt format. So when trying to convert the vectors into a list, I get the 'string indices must be integers' error. I've tried `int(df)`, but I get this: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ID_1\tID_2\n97353\t959\n9232...`. Any ideas how to fix? @JohnSalter; @S3DEV

Comment: @S3DEV despite the apparent intention, OP definitely did not actually have a DataFrame, because that would not produce the output described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it as Pandas dataframe, Try below:

```
data = {'ID_1': [97353, 9723, 128, 124564],
    'ID_2': [959, 19, 20, 18]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID_1','ID_2'])
list1 = []
for i in range(len(df)) : 
  list1.append([df.loc[i, "ID_1"], df.loc[i, "ID_2"]])
print (list1)
##[[97353, 959], [9723, 19], [128, 20], [124564, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work.

```
list1 = []
f = open("file.txt", "r") 
next(f)
for i in f:
  words = i.split()
  for j in range(0, len(words)): 
    words[j] = int(words[j])  
    list1.append(words)

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print them out as tuples inside a list

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
mylist= []

for x in zip(list1,list2):
  mylist.append(x)
```

Output:

[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]